# How to do joint resampling in R

Tags: r, resampling

I have 3 different residual series, which are xts object, and I want to perform join resampling so that I can pick values from the 3 residual series together. Any thoughts on how this can be done?

I was able to use the `resample()` function to do this for one series but I don't think it has the capability to take 3 series as input and perform the operation on them together.

```
resample(as.numeric(residuals1), 2000, replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your desired output is here. How exactly does this resampling need to work?

Comment: Do you mean stratified sampling?

Comment: I am trying to get values from the 3 different xts objects at the same time, which are residuals from 3 different regressions. It can be called Joint residual resampling.